# How make subclass of ParseUser and use it (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to make sub class of ParseUser to use in application. According to [parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-subclasses) i made like this;

```
@ParseClassName("User")
public class User extends ParseUser {



}
```

In normal usage we get ParseUser in static way

```
 ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

This new class "User" , i make an instance like
     User user = new User();

but it's default fields come null.

for example;

```
User user = new User();
String mail = user.getEmail();
```

here it is

```
mail
```

comes null.

How can go over this?

Comment: Do you mean when you initialize User, you want to set default values in constructor?

Comment: Yeap, i can do this with some logic in User.class. But without is there any other way (easy way) ?

Answer (score 5):

You should change from

```
@ParseClassName("User")
```

To

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
```

Then you can get the current user

```
User parseUser = (User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

Now you have the current user with all the fields as an instance of the custom class User and you can operate on it with all the methods you defined